# Cannot format Linux distro

Tags: linux, boot, format, kali-linux

I'm having some trouble with my installation of Kali Linux on my [laptop](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-s-series-netbooks/ideapad-s10-2), so I decided to just throw it all away and format it, then install Kali again. Problem is, while it appears that I have indeed correctly burned the [Kali 32 bit](https://www.kali.org/downloads/) `.iso` onto a Kingston usb stick, when I try to boot from it (either by choosing boot method or changing the boot priority settings entirely, I've tried both) it appears to just boot regularly from the already installed Kali. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like grub is just  screwy   try rebuilding it .

Answer (score 0):

firt go to bios advanced bios features ,priority boot and u have to change the first 1 to usb kingstone flashh drive then back to advanced boot and changed the firt boot section to usb-hdd and second boot to usb -cdRM.AND RESTART your machine it will boot your bootable flash drive